# Using the AWS SES service to send a txt message to a users phone seems impractical? How else?

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, postfix-mta

I am using the AWS SES (Simple Email Service) to handle my application messages.  This works well and uses postfix and stunnel to connect to the AWS SMS service.

The problem happens when I send a mail message to the client phone number using the Google-Fi sms portal: phone-number@msg.fi.google.com.  (Where the sending email address is verified-app-email@xxxxx.com, and the to address is phone-number@msg.fi.google.com)

If the email address phone_number@msg.fi.google.com is verified, the log file shows:

```
Nov 13 21:09:59 xxxxx postfix/pickup[749]: 12C0424154: uid=1000 from=<aaaaaa@xxxxx.com>
Nov 13 21:09:59 xxxxx postfix/cleanup[1364]: 12C0424154: message-id=<95d243f5-633a-7c5b-4c05-24d8a3a4bf5a@xxxxx.com>
Nov 13 21:09:59 xxxxx postfix/qmgr[750]: 12C0424154: from=<aaaaaa@xxxxx.com>, size=739, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 13 21:09:59 xxxxx postfix/smtp[1366]: 12C0424154: to=<phone-number@msg.fi.google.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:2525, delay=0.89, delays=0.02/0.01/0.43/0.44, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok 0100015fb8b830cc-075dcfb4-4254-4cc7-b783-2804f3c99ff3-000000)
Nov 13 21:09:59 xxxxx postfix/qmgr[750]: 12C0424154: removed
```

and things work as expected.

When the email address: phone-number@msg.fi.google.com is not verified, the log file shows:

```
Nov 13 21:06:58 xxxxx postfix/pickup[749]: E93AB24154: uid=1000 from=<aaaaaa@xxxxx.com>
Nov 13 21:06:58 xxxxx postfix/cleanup[1305]: E93AB24154: message-id=<cea2fb09-cffb-201b-2125-128ec7b17d17@xxxxx.com>
Nov 13 21:06:58 xxxxx postfix/qmgr[750]: E93AB24154: from=<aaaaaa@xxxxx.com>, size=739, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 13 21:07:00 xxxxx postfix/smtp[1307]: E93AB24154: to=<phone-number@msg.fi.google.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:2525, delay=1.1, delays=0.01/0.01/0.6/0.46, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: phone-number@msg.fi.google.com (in reply to end of DATA command))
Nov 13 21:07:00 xxxxx postfix/cleanup[1305]: 08BE62B5A5: message-id=<20171114040700.08BE62B5A5@xxxxx.com>
Nov 13 21:07:00 xxxxx postfix/qmgr[750]: 08BE62B5A5: from=<>, size=2938, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 13 21:07:00 xxxxx postfix/bounce[1309]: E93AB24154: sender non-delivery notification: 08BE62B5A5
Nov 13 21:07:00 xxxxx postfix/qmgr[750]: E93AB24154: removed
Nov 13 21:07:00 xxxxx postfix/cleanup[1305]: 0BECF24154: message-id=<20171114040700.08BE62B5A5@xxxxx.com>
Nov 13 21:07:00 xxxxx postfix/qmgr[750]: 0BECF24154: from=<>, size=3065, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 13 21:07:00 xxxxx postfix/local[1311]: 08BE62B5A5: to=<aaaaaa@xxxxx.com>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as 0BECF24154)
Nov 13 21:07:00 xxxxx postfix/qmgr[750]: 08BE62B5A5: removed
Nov 13 21:07:00 xxxxx postfix/smtp[1307]: 0BECF24154: to=<yyyyy@gmail.com>, orig_to=<aaaaaa@xxxxx.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:2525, delay=0.59, delays=0/0/0.52/0.07, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 501 Invalid MAIL FROM address provided (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Nov 13 21:07:00 xxxxx postfix/qmgr[750]: 0BECF24154: removed
```

and the txt message never reaches the phone.

SO if the email address phone-number@msg.fi.google.com is not verified, is there a way to chain back to the original email address that is verified with AWS SMS and not need to verify the second email address: phone-number@msg.fi.google.com ???

The sendmail command that kicks this off in either case is very simple:

sendMail: from: aaaaaa@xxxxx.com 
          to: phone-number@msg.fi.google.com,
          subject: sdfsdf, 
          content: fasdfgasdg asdfsadfasdfasdfsadfasf

Comment: How about if you use SNS topic and subscribe it with user's phone number and you can simply publish that topic programmatically. [link](http://www.tryyourskill.com/aws/send-sms-using-aws-sdk)

Comment: That seems like a much simpler suggestion.  Then I can just send SMS messages directly.  I hadn't yet used the SNS service, so thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You need to ask AWS to take you out of sandbox node.  You don't have to verify the addresses of people you send to unless you are not in production mode.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have opened up a service request to be taken out of sanbox mode.  I didn't yet realize that I needed to do that.  The suggestion to use the SNS service is also helpful, but for now I will stay with the simple email  to an email-sms portal.